# IOException when trying to run new ballerina project

Tags: ballerina

Tools:

- MacOS 10.15.6
- Ballerina distribution slp4
- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3
- Ballerina plugin 1.2.8

I created a new Ballerina project in IntelliJ, then added a module named `main` containing one file, `main.bal`.

`main.bal` contains a `main()` function.

Clicking the green arrow next to it gives me this output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/1.2.8/libexec/distributions/ballerina-slp4/bin/ballerina run --sourceroot /Users/me/ballerina/my-project main
Compiling source
    me/main:0.1.0

Creating balos
    target/balo/main-2020r2-any-0.1.0.balo
    target/bin/main.jar

Running executables

error: Error occurred while running the executable java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The same thing happens when I open a terminal window and do `ballerina run main`.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Ballerina is installed via Homebrew on macOS. Could you please try with the mac installer? We will fix this soon.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but after downloading I got this error message:

`“ballerina-macos-installer-x64-1.2.8.pkg” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.`

`This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.`

Comment: And I still get that message when downloading now. Is there any option that actually works on Macs right now?

Comment: I've now tried downloading the .zip distribution and installling adoptopenjdk8 directly, and after all that I'm still getting `error: Error occurred while running the executable java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`.

Comment: As of now, Could you please remove the java dependencies inside the dependencies directory? If you install ballerina via homebrew, it will be installed ```/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/1.2.8/libexec/``` in this location.

Comment: I deleted my current installation, reinstalled via homebrew, pulled slp4 again, and now I am still getting the same error.

Comment: After pulling a distribution, you have to delete the downloaded dependencies again. Please check whether is any JDK dependencies inside the dependencies directory. If it is there, please remove it.

Comment: Which dependencies directory do you mean? I deleted all previous installations including their dependencies directory before reinstalling from homebrew.

Comment: When you install ballerina via homebrew, it will be installed  ```/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/1.2.8/libexec/``` in this location. Inside this, you can see the directory named 'dependencies'. After installing ballerina, please check whether any dependency is there? If so, please remove that.

Comment: This happens for me `2201.8.0` and `2201.8.1`. I'm using ubuntu 22.04.LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved after removing the ballerina installation fully and deleting its files.

For ubuntu I used: `sudo dpkg -r <ballerina-package>` and `sudo dpkg --purge <ballerina-package>`

And then, I manually deleted the content in `ballerina` installation and `.ballerina` directory in the home directory.